# Duvida HighCharts duplicar Label

Tags: javascript, highcharts

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como que eu duplico para o lado esquerdo esses dados dentro do circulo em vermelho?

```
yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis

                    opposite: true,

                    title: {text: metrica, x:35 },
                    labels: {align: 'right', x:35},
                    gridLineColor: '#b1b7b0',
                    gridLineWidth:2

                },
                    { // Secondary yAxis
                        opposite: false,

                        title: {text: metrica, x:-35 },
                        labels: {
                            align: 'left', 
                            x:-35,
                            formatter: function() {
                                return this.data
                            }
                        },
                        gridLineColor: '#000000',
                        gridLineWidth:2


                }]
```

Comment: @Felipe Sabe como faz ?

Comment: Vou aproveitar sua pergunta pra abrir um parêntese para uma pergunta que eu tenho. No meu hightchart o eixo y do lado esquerdo está apresentando valores diferentes do eixo y do lado direito. Como igualar?

Comment: @MarianaFerreira tem como mandar o seu codigo para que eu posso saber como inserir outros valores no eixo?

Comment: Vou mandar a pergunta, nela tem meu código: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/243912/eixos-y-diferentes-em-highcharts

Answer (score 0):

é só você colocar dois yAxis, por exemplo:

```
yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
        min: 10,
        tickInterval: 10,
        labels: {
            format: '{value}',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: '',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        },
    },{ 
            min: 10,
        tickInterval: 10,// Secondary yAxis
        title: {
            text: '',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        },
        labels: {
            format: '{value}',
            style: {
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[1]
            }
        },
        opposite: true,
    }],
```

e isto diz qual será o lado:

```
opposite: true,
```